# Inconsistency calling TextField text in setOnKeyTyped

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a typing test in Java with JavaFX. I want to compare the text that is being typed in a TextField to the defined random words. However, the TextField only updates with the letter just typed sometimes and not all the times. The following code is where this problem is occurring.

```
    field.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {

        String typingWord = field.getText();

        if(     typingWord.isEmpty()          && 
                e.getCharacter().charAt(0) == '\b' && 
                !(typedWords.size() == 0)          &&
                typingWord.equals(previousWord)){

            field.setText(typedWords.get(typedWords.size() - 1));
            typedWords.remove(typedWords.size() - 1);
            field.positionCaret(typingWord.length());
            index--;
        }

        //compare random words to typed words

        if (Character.isWhitespace(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))) {

            typedWords.set(index, typingWord);
            field.clear();
            e.consume();
            index++;
        }

        previousWord = field.getText();
    });
```

Is this purely due to the speed of my computer or is it just a bug in JavaFX?

Comment: Sorry for the unreadable if statements. I set the action to onkeypressed() but that just makes the problem more constant. It does not update field.getText() with the character that I pressed until after the fact. onkeyreleaced() works fine but I cannot test what the character that I just pressed. So I cannot test if it was a space so I can clear the field.

Comment: i will delete that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sir  i do not know what you want to do but i want to help, so in your `onKeyPressed()` or `onKeyReleased()`, it gives a `KeyEvent` that is `e` in your case, you can use that in place of `Character.isWhitespace()` & `e.getCharacter().charAt(0)` and also `/b`

To get your `KeyCode`

```
field.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
      KeyCode kc = e.getCode(); // your keycode here is the character you just pressed
```

now with the KeyCode you can check for a whole lot of goodies,without falling to character

equality checks

`if(kc == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)` //checking for your backspace

`if(kc.isWhitespaceKey())` // your enter, tabs, space etc

also you can make use of these methods

`TextField.deletePreviousChar();`,`TextField.deleteNextChar();` that might save you all the selection before clearing. if you want to clear like 10 of them then loop it 10 times

lastly why do you check for emptiness & later check if its not empty

Comment: I understand how KeyCode works but sometimes the character that I press with my keyboard is added to field and sometimes not. The only way that prevents this is if I use setOnKeyReleased() so the field updates with the new character. However, setOnKeyReceased() does not allow me to test the character that I typed. (int)(e.getCharecter.charAt(0)) always returns 0. Sorry for the confusing problem.