# loading script from directory

Tags: php, html

I'm not even sure if this is what I'm asking but for example on this link:
[Inconsistency calling TextField text in setOnKeyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455527/inconsistency-calling-textfield-text-in-setonkeytyped)

After the questions/ is 33455527 which is a directory, right? I'm assuming stack overflow doesn't create a folder for every single question asked so it has to be a script loaded or something right? I'm try to determine what that is and how to replicate it on my site.

Comment: Google "mod_rewrite"

Comment: use `$_GET` to get the id and get the record according it

Comment: URL rewriting, dynamic routing, or whatever or similar names people may have for this functionaity is a pretty important concept in modern web applications.  Unfortunately "how to" do this is a very broad topic not ideally suited for the SO Q & A format.  You really need to do some basic research in the area that is relevant to your application platform and formulate more specific questions where you are running into problems.

Comment: @Andrew - That's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @j08691 but it does involves the GET parameter...the number after the questions should be the id of the row...but of course you need `mod_rewrite` if wanted to be SEO friendly